# How to insert dependencies in local package if npm package is installed globally

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm, package

I have installed few npm packages globally but it does not show any dependencies in any of my package.json files. Which npm command should I use to apply dependencies in all of my package.json files?

Comment: `npm install packageName --save` for local; `npm install -g packageName` for global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Globally installed dependencies won't list in your local `package.json` file. You should still be able to use them `requiring/importing` into your project.

if you want to save a dependency in your `package.json` as well when you install it, us `--save` flag with npm install command.
for example

```
npm install --save express
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to add a package which is installed globally to locally or vice versa.

1. When a package is installed globally, it is normally used as a command in the terminal. For example, `create-react-app` or `express-generator`. You might install these packages globally to use them as commands in the terminal to build React or Express app (with default scaffold).
2. When a package is installed locally, it means you want to use it within the application. For example, `jsonwebtoken`. You should install this package locally so that it can be used within the application and when somebody else clones your project they can install this package as well via `npm install` command.

So, the suggestion is, install the package globally if you're going to use it as a command, else install the package locally within the application. Don't mix them.